# inserting if statement into css class in html

Tags: php

I am trying to insert the following if statement into a class but getting the  unexpected T_IF error;

```
class="color_icon_filter '. if ($link_data['id']==$link_data['text']) {$active} .' "
```

is this not possible or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You shoud open PHP tags to be interpreted server side.

```
class="color_icon_filter <?php if ($link_data['id']==$link_data['text']) {echo $active} ?>"
```

**EDIT**

Or if you're already in PHP tags

```
echo 'class="color_icon_filter '.($link_data['id']==$link_data['text'] ? $active : '').'"';
```

Comment: The question says they are getting an unexpected T_IF error. That means the code in the question starts inside a string. You'd need to make additional modifications to the code beyond changing what has been shared already.

Comment: an alternative approach is to use the terinary if format... `($link_data['id']==$link_data['text']?$active:"in-active")`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to concatenate an `if` statement onto a string.

You can do this instead:

```
$string = "123";
if ($bar) {
   $string .= "456";
}
$string .= "789";
```

or this:

```
if ($bar) {
    $baz = "456";
} else {
    $baz = "";
}
$string = "123" . $baz . "789";
```

You could also use [a ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), but your if condition is (relatively) long, so it risks making your code look even more like line noise.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to concat in an if statement.

I'm assuming there's an echo in front of that line.  You can either convert that to sprintf (http://php.net/sprintf) or put the if before the echo line, set the value of $active, and then concat in just the variable.

Personally, I think sprintf/printf is your better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an if statement in the middle of an assignment operation, but there are ways to achieve your desired result:

```
$active = '';
if ( $link_data['id']==$link_data['text'] ) {
    $active = 'active';
}
$class = "color_icon_filter $active";
```

or a shorter way via the ternary operator:

```
$active = ( $link_data['id']==$link_data['text'] ) ? 'active' : '';
$class = "color_icon_filter $active";
```